# Uploading Base 64 String/Image to Azure storage image is coming out blank Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to store base64 encoded image to azure blob storage. PFB the code snippet for the same.
File is getting created but it is coming as broken image.

[image: image uploaded]

**Code Snippet**

```
String mimeType = extractMimeType(imageBase64Encoded).replace("image/", "");
String fileName = "image." + mimeType;
BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .containerName(containerName)
                .buildClient();
BlobClient client = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);
String base64Data = imageBase64Encoded.split(",")[1];
byte[] base64DataBytes = base64Data.getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64DataBytes);
client.upload(dataStream, base64DataBytes.length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the base64 encoded string to byte[] and use that byte[] to store the image.

```java
String mimeType = extractMimeType(imageBase64Encoded).replace("image/", "");
String fileName = "image." + mimeType;
BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .containerName(containerName)
                .buildClient();
BlobClient client = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);
String base64Data = imageBase64Encoded.split(",")[1];
byte[] base64DataBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Data);
ByteArrayInputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64DataBytes);
client.upload(dataStream, base64DataBytes.length);
```